# Java: How would I go about filtering a String with regex to find a specific charset?

Tags: java, regex, matching, dollar-sign

I'm reading from a text file and I'm trying to filter:

```
::Tile(1,8), 92, water.png
```

so that it can find:

```
92, water.png
```

I have done this with:

```
Matcher m =Pattern.compile("\\),\\s([\\d+\\s*,\\s*\\w+\\s*]+)").matcher(statement);
```

where statement is the original String

However, when I use:

```
::Tile(1,8), 92b, water.png
```

as the original String, it completely ignores the intended regex match and gives:

```
92b, water.png
```

I've tried using the $ sign at the end to no avail. I've tried getting around using the + at the end of the regex inside ([...]) which doesn't help either.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\\),\\s(\\d+\\s*,\\s*[\\w.]+\\s*)
```

Guess you wanted this.`[]` is not what you think.It is a *character class*.Defining a pattern inside it is useless.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/10